# Как добавить прозрачность в ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Как добавить прозрачность в ListView?

Когда прокручиваю надо чтобы нижняя и верхняя граница была прозрачной. как увеличить height у этих двух вещей?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос точнее, вы хотите transparent элементов или увеличить высоту

Comment: @АлексейСоловьев, обновил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо анимировать создаваемые элементы. Можно использовать подготовленную анимацию fade_in. Для это добавьте всего одну строчку кода в ваш адаптер.

```
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, android.R.anim.fade_in));
```

### До:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### После:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нет это не то  ..